# There is an exception while running the code in selenium grid for IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

This is the class I have created. rest is auto-generated by eclipse.
now all i want to do is run it.

```
`@BeforeTest
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException
{
    baseUrl = "www.google.com";
    nodeURL = "http://192.168.3.12:5566/wd/hub";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");

    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

    capability.setBrowserName("Internet Explorer");

    capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL),capability );

}`
```

And the exception I get is as follows:

FAILED: simpleTest
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to navigate to www.google.com . This usually means that a call to the COM method IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds

Comment: Have you ensured that Internet Explorer is configured as suggested in  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration

Comment: `DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();`.... ?!!!